# Missing Status Bar in Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, statusbar

*Note: This question and answer is a full copy from [Kelly Brownsbergers Blog](http://kellybrownsberger.com/?p=581). I do post it as a convenience to others.*

From time to time, my status bar disappears.  I used to believe this was due to a botched install or add-in.  I recently upgraded to Team System Test Edition, and my status bar again disappeared.  For the last few weeks I’ve been trying to figure out a time to do a full reinstall.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Today, I discovered this is a setting in Visual Studio (duh). Go to Tools –> Options –> Environment –> General section and check the “Show status bar” checkbox:

And you’ll have your status bar back.

See: [Kelly Brownsbergers Blog](http://kellybrownsberger.com/?p=581)

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for that option and couldn't find it.